# Объединить правила условного форматирования

Tags: excel, google-spreadsheet

Есть 4 объединенные ячейки: `B1:D1, E1:G1, H1:J1, K1:M1`.
Есть ячейка `N1`. Все ячейки имеют текстовые значения. Хочу закрашивать фон объединенных ячеек в зеленый цвет, если их значение `=N1`.

Как удалось решить проблему: четыре правила вида
`=if(B1=N1;true;false), =if(E1=N1;true;false), ...`
соответственно для диапазонов `B1:D1, E1:G1, ...`.

Как эти правила объединить в одно?
Пробовал создать правило вида `=if(B1=N1;true;false)` для диапазона `B1:M1`, не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Формула условного форматирования (УФ) пишется для левой верхней ячейки диапазона.
УФ в *Excel* само умеет определять истинность выражения:

```
=B$1=$N$1
```

Применяется к:

```
=$B$1:$M$1
```

> правило вида `=if(B1=N1;true;false)` для диапазона `B1:M1`

Ваше правило не работает, т.к. не закреплена ссылка на ячейку `N1`. При этом, к примеру, `E1` сравнивается с `Q1`

Comment: Google Sheets не позволяет сохранить такой диапазон (`$B$1:$M$1`), в результате сохраняет как `B1:M1`. Спасибо

Comment: *Google*-таблицы - это не *Excel*. Хоть и похожи, но различий много. В *Excel* показанное форматирование работает. Проверьте, возможно для *Google* незакрепленный диапазон в УФ - это нормально и фрматирование будет работать...